# Kaminari Pagination with Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, kaminari

I'm using Kaminari on my site with a 'load more' button to show another six items when clicked. It works great but when I try to add a sorting order it's not passing the params to the link_to_next_page def although I can see it in the html...

The other question asked on this said to pass the params to the link_to_next_page but it doesn't make a difference.

Example: When I try to sort by lowest price > highest price the first six items are sorted but on 'load more' the sorting order is random.

Can anyone advise here??

Thanks.

Some code...

index.html.erb

```
 <div id="offers">
    <%= render :partial => @television_offers %>
  </div>

  <%= link_to_next_page @television_offers, 'Load More', :remote => true, :id=>"load_more_link", :params => params %>   </div>
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#offers').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @television_offers)%>");
$('#load_more_link').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@television_offers, 'Load More', :remote => true, :id=>'load_more_link', :params => params))%>");
```

application_helper.rb

```
def link_to_next_page(scope, name, options = {}, &block)
  param_name = options.delete(:param_name) || Kaminari.config.param_name
  link_to_unless scope.last_page?, name, {param_name => (scope.current_page + 1)},   options.merge(:rel => 'next') do
  block.call if block
  end
end
```

television_offers_controller.rb

```
def index

  @television_offers = TelevisionOffer.page(params[:page]).per(6)

  if params[:filter] == "large_screens"
    @television_offers = @television_offers.large_size
  elsif params[:filter] == "small_screens"
    @television_offers = @television_offers.small_size
  elsif params[:filter] == "price"

  if params[:order] == "asc"
    @television_offers = @television_offers.asc(:offer_price)
  else
    @television_offers = @television_offers.desc(:offer_price)
  end

  else
    @television_offers = @television_offers.best
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing the same problem this was solved by simply updating kaminari to the latest version